# Is there any difference between aggregate([{:$project => {:_id=>1}}]) and projection({:_id=>1}) in mongodb?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3

Both of the two expressions below in mongodb return the same value:

```
db.collection.find().aggregate([{:$project => {:_id=>1}}])

db.collection.find().projection({:_id=>1})
```

While I just wondering is there any difference between them?

Comment: I think so, I like the question.